# I am hyperlinking a page with specific section

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In a wordpress site when the user one clicks on a link, the user will be redirected to the next page where a specific anchor name is hard coded so the user will land on that section.

I am working on a wordpress default script that scrolls to top.

I would like to stop scrolling when a user lands on the page with an anchor name.

http://example.com/services/ -> scroll to top
http://example.com/services/#digital -> do not scroll to top

Comment: Please post the code you have so far, e.g. the relevant part of the script.

Comment: multiple j query and java script files using Avada theme default